# Solaris compatible smart card / token

Tags: solaris, token

I'm looking for a smart card (+reader) and (or) usb token compatible with Solaris 10 x86 and OpenSolaris. Can someone suggest?

Comment: I was going to suggest the Solaris Hardware Comparability List (http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/hcl/) but I couldn't actually find any entries that seemed to match :(

Comment: yes, actually I haven't seen any Sun products in this niche except a cards for sunrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a SMC Microsystems [SCR331](http://www.scmmicro.com/security/view_product_en.php?PID=2) reader which works just fine.